# GUI: Highlight the Path It Takes for A Maze?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, actionlistener, jlabel

I am working on a partner project where my partner creates a solver class for the game while my part is to create the MazeGUI.

When you click on the Solve `JButton`, it is supposed to highlight the path it takes on the GUI itself, but it only highlights where it "ends" which is the most bottom right corner which isn't supposed to be accessible since it is a "W". If there is a Solution, "F" will turn into "RIP", and if there is no solution to the maze, it should have a `JLabel` saying the maze is unsolvable.

How can I input all of these in my code under the ActionListener for solveButton?

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class MazeGUI {
    String appName = "Zombie Attack!";
    JLabel appNameLabel;

    private JFrame frame;
    private JPanel buttonPanel, solvePanel;
    private JButton solveButton;
    // private JLabel noSolutionLabel;

    private final int rowCount = 10;
    private final int colCount = 10;
    private final int startRow = 0;
    private final int startCol = 1;
    private final int endRow = rowCount - 1;
    private final int endCol = colCount - 2;

    String[][] map;

    private void createAndShowGui() {
        frame = new JFrame("Zombie Attack!");

        solveButton = new JButton("Solve");

        map = new String[rowCount][colCount];
        buttonPanel = new JPanel();

        buttonPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(rowCount, colCount, 2, 2));

        appNameLabel = new JLabel(appName);
        for (int rows = 0; rows < rowCount; rows++) {
            for (int columns = 0; columns < colCount; columns++) {

                map[rows][columns] = " ";

                final JLabel jlabel = new JLabel("");
                jlabel.setBackground(Color.BLACK);

                if (rows == startRow && columns == startCol) {
                    jlabel.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
                    jlabel.setForeground(Color.MAGENTA);
                    jlabel.setText("S");
                    map[startRow][startCol] = "S";
                }

                if (rows == endRow && columns == endCol) {
                    jlabel.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
                    jlabel.setForeground(Color.MAGENTA);
                    jlabel.setText("F");
                    map[endRow][endCol] = "F";
                }

                if (!(rows == startRow && columns == startCol || rows == endRow
                        && columns == endCol)) {
                    if (rows == 0 || rows == rowCount - 1 || columns == 0
                            || columns == colCount - 1) {
                        jlabel.setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
                        map[rows][columns] = "W";
                    }
                }


                final int rc = rows;
                final int cc = columns;


                jlabel.addMouseListener(new MouseListener() {
                    boolean clicked = false;

                    @Override
                    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                        if (clicked == false) {
                            clicked = true;
                            jlabel.setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
                            map[rc][cc] = "W";


                        } else {
                            clicked = false;
                            jlabel.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
                            map[rc][cc] = "";

                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
                    }

                });

                solveButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {

                        MazeSolver solver;
                        solver = new MyMazeSolver();
                        solver.solve(map);
                        jlabel.setBackground(Color.RED);
                        jlabel.setForeground(Color.GREEN);
                        jlabel.setText("RIP");

                        for (int i = 0; i < map.length; i++){
                            for (int j = 0; j < map[0].length; j++){
                                System.out.print(map[i][j] + " ");
                            }
                            System.out.println();
                        }
                    }
                });
                System.out.print(map[rows][columns] + " ");
                buttonPanel.add(jlabel);

                jlabel.setOpaque(true);
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
        frame.add(appNameLabel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        frame.add(buttonPanel);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setSize(500, 500);
        frame.add(solveButton, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MazeGUI maze = new MazeGUI();
        maze.createAndShowGui();
    }
}
```

Here is the solver's interface:

```
public interface MazeSolver {
    public String[][] solve(String[][] map);
}
```

Here is my partner's code (Coordinate Class):

```
public class Coordinate {

    private int row;
    private int col;

    public Coordinate(int row, int col) {
        this.row = row;
        this.col = col;
    }

    public int getRow() {
        return row;
    }

    public int getCol() {
        return col;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Coordinate [row=" + row + ", col=" + col + "]";
    }
}
```

MyMazeSolver class:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MyMazeSolver implements MazeSolver {
    private static ArrayList<Coordinate> coordinates = new ArrayList<Coordinate>();

    private int row;
    private int col;

    @Override
    public String[][] solve(String[][] map) {
        startingPos(map);
        //for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
        do{
            makeMove(map);

            if (nextToF(map, row, col)) {
                System.out.println(row + "" + col);
                map[row][col] = "X";
            } else {

                if (isExplorable(map, row, col)) {
                    map[row][col] = "D";
                } else {
                    map[row][col] = "X";
                }

                if(deadEnd(map, row, col)){

                }
            }
            addCoordinates(row, col);
            //}
        }while(!isEnded(map));
        print(map);

        // delete printCoordinates
        printCoordinates();
        return map;
    }

    public void startingPos(String[][] map) {
        for (int i = 0; i < map.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < map[0].length; j++) {
                if (map[i][j].contains("S")) {
                    row = i;
                    col = j;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public boolean clear(String[][] map, int row, int col) {


        if (row <= 0 || col <= 0 ||row > map.length) {
            return false;
        }
        if (col <= 0 ||  col > map[0].length) {
            return false;
        }

        if ("S".equals(map[row][col])) {
            return false;
        }
        if ("W".equals(map[row][col])) {
            return false;
        }
        if ("X".equals(map[row][col])) {
            return false;
        }
        if ("D".equals(map[row][col])) {
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

    public void makeMove(String[][] map) {
        if (clear(map, row + 1, col)) {
            row++;
        } else if (clear(map, row, col - 1)) {
            col--;
        } else if (clear(map, row, col + 1)) {
            col++;
        } else if (clear(map, row, col)) {
            row--;
        }

    }

    public boolean explorable(String[][] map, int row, int col) {
        if (row > map.length) {
            return false;
        }
        if (col > map[0].length) {
            return false;
        }

        if (map[row][col].equals("S")) {
            return false;
        }
        if (map[row][col].equals("W")) {
            return false;
        }
        if (map[row][col].equals("X")) {
            return false;
        }
        if (map[row][col].equals("D")) {
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

    public boolean isExplorable(String[][] map, int row, int col) {
        int squares = 0;

        if (explorable(map, row + 1, col)) {
            squares++;
        }
        if (explorable(map, row, col - 1)) {
            squares++;
        }
        if (explorable(map, row, col + 1)) {
            squares++;
        }
        if (explorable(map, row - 1, col)) {
            squares++;
        }

        if (squares > 1) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public void addCoordinates(int row, int col) {
        coordinates.add(new Coordinate(row, col));
    }

    public void printCoordinates() {
        for (int i = 0; i < coordinates.size(); i++) {

            System.out.println(coordinates.get(i));
        }
    }

    public boolean nextToF(String[][] map, int row, int col) {
        if ("F".equals(map[row + 1][col])) {
            // row++;
            map[row + 1][col] = ("RIP");
            return true;
        } else if ("F".equals(map[row][col - 1])) {
            // col--;
            map[row][col - 1] = "RIP";
            return true;
        } else if ("F".equals(map[row][col + 1])) {
            // col++;
            map[row][col + 1] = "RIP";
            return true;
        } else if ("F".equals(map[row - 1][col])) {
            // row--;
            map[row - 1][col] = "RIP";
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public boolean deadEnd(String[][] map, int row, int col) {
        int deadEnds = 0;

        if (row > map.length) {
            deadEnds++;
        }
        if (col > map[0].length) {
            deadEnds++;
        }
        if (map[row][col].equals("S")) {
            deadEnds++;
        }
        if (map[row][col].equals("W")) {
            deadEnds++;
        }
        if (map[row][col].equals("X")) {
            deadEnds++;
        }
        if (map[row][col].equals("D")) {
            deadEnds++;
        }

        if (deadEnds == 4) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }

    }

    public void findD(){

    }

    public boolean isEnded(String[][] map) {
        for (int i = 0; i < map.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < map.length; j++) {
                if (map[i][j].equals("RIP")) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    public void print(String[][] map) {
        for (int i = 0; i < map.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < map[0].length; j++) {
                System.out.print(map[i][j]);

            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

> I call his class under the solveButton's ActionListener but I don't
>   know how to update the String[][] map when you click on a JLabel. For
>   example if I click a JLabel at (5,5) the map will update map[5][5] to
>   "W" instead of an empty String.

The problem here is, you are relying on information that doesn't change.

```
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
    if (clicked == false) {
        clicked = true;
        jlabel.setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
        map[rowCount - 1][colCount - 1] = "W";

    } else {
        clicked = false;
        jlabel.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        //map[rowCount - 1][colCount -1 ] = "";

    }
}
```

In your code, you are relying on `rowCount` and `colCount`, which doesn't (and probably shouldn't) change, but instead, only effects the last element.  There's no relation ship between the `JLabel` and the map entry.

What you need to be able to do is is provide some kind of link.  In this case, I would normally use a `Map` of some kind, keyed to the `JLabel` and maintaining the reference I need to loop up the `map` values.

For example...

```
String[][] map;
// 1
private Map<JLabel, Point> labelMap;
//...
private void createAndShowGui() {
    //...
    map = new String[rowCount][colCount];
    // 2
    labelMap = new HashMap<>(rowCount * colCount);
        //...
        // 3
        labelMap.put(jlabel, new Point(rows - 1, columns - 1));
        jlabel.addMouseListener(new MouseListener() {
```

1. Create a new instance variable of type `Map`
2. Create a new instance of `labelMap`, using `HashMap`
3. Associate the `row`/`column` with the given label

Then in your `MouseListener`, you need to  get the `JLabel` that was clicked, get the associated `row`/`column` for the `map` array and make your updates...

```
jlabel.addMouseListener(new MouseListener() {
    boolean clicked = false;

    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        // Get the source of the event
        JLabel label = (JLabel)e.getComponent();
        // Get the map indices associated with the given label
        Point point = labelMap.get(label);

        // Flip the clicked state
        clicked = !clicked;
        // Update the state accordingly...
        if (clicked) {
            jlabel.setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
            map[point.x][point.y] = "W";
        } else {
            jlabel.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
            map[point.x][point.y] = "";
        }
    }
```

> Also, when you click on the Solve JButton, it is supposed to highlight
>   the path it takes, but it only highlights where it ends. If there is a
>   Solution, "F" will turn into "RIP", and if there is no solution to the
>   maze, it should have a JLabel saying the maze is unsolvable.

There a series of problems why this isn't working, and you should have seen the exceptions been thrown when they occurred.

This first problem I hit was a `NullPointerException` which was been caused in your `clear` method at this line `if (map[row][col].equals("S"))) {`

This immediately told me that the value of `map[row][col]` was `null`.  Don't know if it should be or not, don't really care as it's easily fixed using...

```
if ("S".equals(map[row][col]))) {
```

You will need to do this for the other `if` statements in this method.

The second problem I hit was a `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` which was been caused in your `makeMove` method

```
} else if (clear(map, row, col - 1)) {
//...
} else if (clear(map, row - 1, col)) {
```

The main problem here is, what happens when `col` or `row` are `0`?  You're not making a boundary check for this eventually....

You could fix this in your `clear` method using...

```
public boolean clear(String[][] map, int row, int col) {
    if (row < 0 || row > map.length) {
        return false;
    }
    if (col < 0 || col > map[0].length) {
        return false;
    }
```

For example...

You `nextToF` method is causing a simular problem

Comment: Okay, I was able to figure out how to update the String[][] map using another method instead of using Map. I also edited some of my partner's code with the null exception too for the clear method. I updated my code as well in the original post. However, how is the GUI supposed to highlight the path it takes? If all the errors are gone, it will highlight the entire grid red with "RIP" instead of highlighting the correct path and changing "F" in the end to "RIP"

Comment: Also, if I were to block off the path completely from the ending "F", it gives me "OutOfMemoryError": Java heap space.

Comment: @user3376836 Sounds like you have a stack over flow issue.  Best choice is to place a break point in your code and run a debugger over it...

Comment: How about highlighting the path issue? I still have no idea how to code that part in the solveButton's ActionListener. I would assume you would use "if" statements, but what will be the statement itself?